# How to select from two identical table?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table but partitioned by month, for example

table_202201, table_202202

I would like to select from two tables, how can I do that?

```
select * from table_202201, table_202202
```

What I want is, for example,

Say table_202201:

```
id name date
1. a.   20220101
2. b.   20220101
```

table_202202:

```
id name date
11. aa.   20220201
22. bb.   20220201
```

I would like to get results like this:

```
id name date
1. a.   20220101
2. b.   20220101
11. aa.   20220201
22. bb.   20220201
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use `UNION ALL` instead of `,` (`CROSS JOIN`)

```
SELECT * FROM table_202201
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_202202
```

I would use explicitly specify  columns which you want to `select` instead `*`

```
SELECT id,name,date
FROM (
    SELECT id,name,date FROM table_202201
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,name,date FROM table_202202
) t1
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: In the first example, as no individual `ORDER BY` can be used for each SELECT statement between UNION, so the sorting order is based on the default order for each. Does it mean the sequence is based on the PK index if there is a PK ,or based on the INSERT sequence of data without a PK ?

Comment: I provide second sample for user modification question which might want to `ORDER BY id`, as you say we need to use `ORDER BY` if want the result be ordered.